# Can't use router-link inside Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Ok so I started a basic VueJS with the VueCli.

This is my setup:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/home"><span>Home</span></router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'home',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'HomeView'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**index.js** from the router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/pages/Home'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    }
  ]
})
```

**main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {App}
})

new Vue({
  el: '#navigation-bar',
  template: '<NavigationBar/>',
  components: {NavigationBar}
})
```

This works perfectly fine. The routerlink works and display the Home.vue.

However I created a NavigationBar Component:

**NavigationBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div><span>Test</span>
    <router-link to="/home"><span>Home</span></router-link></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'navigationBar',
    data () {
      return {
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I now delete the router-link in the App.vue and add the navigation-bar ID I cant see the router-link. But the NavigationBar gets loaded, because I see the Test Span:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="navigation-bar"></div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Why doesnt it work? The router-link is just inside a template and I get no error message.

Comment: Console errors? Did you import the navigation bar to the app?